# how to add a "preview" button to a webform submission

Tags: webforms

I am using version 8x-5.2 of webform.  I cant see an option to add a preview button.  Can someone explain where to add this button, or do i have to use a later version of the webform module to get this ? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

in the webform you go to "settings" "form" and at the bottom there is an option for "Form Preview Settings"